# Unknown issue with comparing 2 different length arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to compare a larger column/array with a smaller column/array to see if the smaller columns values are included in the larger array. The script looks at 4 different columns (Check numbers and check amounts) and attempts to root out row locations where either:

The check numbers in column C do not match

The check numbers in C match but the amounts in column D are not the same

When the arrays are compared and they are exactly the same with only 1 or 2 manual changes being made the code works perfect fine. But I need to check the cashedCheck sheet to be compared to OpenCheck Sheet and find the differences if any. Currently the correct check numbers in column C are never counted as correct and it counts the entire length of the CashedCheck sheet as being invalid (As seen in my console log) I am unsure what I am doing wrong. As you can see in the screenshots both sheets have very different values from  each other but some of the values do match and I am trying to find what rows have different values in column D Or Column C.

[image: Sheet 2]

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Console Log]

Here is the code

```
  function CHK_BothChecks_V5_StackOverFlow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("OpenChecks");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("CashedChecks");
  var rg1 = sh1.getRange("C1:D" + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var rg2 = sh2.getRange("C1:D" + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var correctChecks = 0;
  var invalidChecks = 0;
  var invalidAmounts = 0; 
  for (var i = 0; i < rg2.length; i++) {  
    if (rg1[i][0] == rg2[i][0]) {
      correctChecks++;
    } 
    if(rg1[i][0] == rg2[i][0] && rg1[i][1] !== rg2[i][1]) {
      invalidAmounts++;
      var amtIndex = sh1.getRange(i + 1, 2).getRow();
      console.log("Incongruent amound found at row " + amtIndex);
    } if (rg1[i][0] !== rg2[i][0]) {
      var index = sh1.getRange(i + 1, 2).getRow();
      invalidChecks++;
      console.log(index); 
    }
  }
  console.log("Total number of valid check numbers is " + correctChecks);
  console.log("Total number of invalid check numbers is " + invalidChecks);
  console.log("Total number of invalid amounts is " + invalidAmounts);
}
```

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output or  add input table and expected output table as text table(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding tables greatly increases your chances of getting an answer, as it is easier to copy/paste. Also, what is the error you are getting? Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I know that it is not a script, but it will help you with troubleshooting. Have you tried `vlookup` (with/w/out `arrayformula`) to compare chq numbers on one list to the other, and then text the chq value if a match is found.

Comment: **`DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question.` from [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match "Cashed" cheques against "Open" cheques.

- If both the check number AND value match - then it is a `correctChecks`
- If the check number matches but the value does not match, then it is a `invalidAmounts`
- if the check number does not match, then it is an `invalidChecks`

The OP has the right idea - to loop through the checks but the likelihood that a check is on the same line in both lists is very small. It is better to use an alternative to find a match.

The solution uses `indexOf`

- where a match is found, the index number on the array is returned
- where a match is NOT found, a value of "-1" is returned.

---

```
function CHK_BothChecks_V5_StackOverFlow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Open");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Cashed");
  var rg1 = sh1.getRange("C1:D" + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var openChqNum = rg1.map(function(e){return e[0];})
  var rg2 = sh2.getRange("C1:D" + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues()
  var correctChecks = 0;
  var invalidChecks = 0;
  var invalidAmounts = 0; 
  // test all cashed cheques against open cheques
  for (var i = 0; i < rg2.length; i++) {
    var result = openChqNum.indexOf(rg2[i][0])
    //Logger.log("i="+i+", cashed chq# = "+rg2[i][0]+", result = "+result)
    if (result !== -1){
      // cheque number matches
      var cashedValue = rg2[i][1]
      var openValue = rg1[result][1]
      var proofValue = cashedValue-openValue
      if (proofValue == 0){
        // cheque value matches
        correctChecks++
        Logger.log("CORRECTCHQ: i="+i+", cashed chq# = "+rg2[i][0]+", cashed value = "+rg2[i][1]+", correct checks = "+correctChecks)
        //Logger.log(correctChecks) // DEBUG
      }
      else
      {
        // cheque value does not match
        invalidAmounts++
        Logger.log("INVALID AMOUNT: i="+i+", cashed chq# = "+rg2[i][0]+"cashed value = "+cashedValue+", open Value = "+openValue+" proof value = "+proofValue+", invalid Amounts = "+invalidAmounts)
        //Logger.log(invalidAmounts) // DEBUG
      }
    }else{
      // result = -1
      // no matching cheque
      invalidChecks++
      Logger.log("INVALID CHQ: i="+i+", cashed chq# = "+rg2[i][0]+", cashed value = "+cashedValue+", Invalid checks = "+invalidChecks)
      // Logger.log(invalidChecks) // DEBUG
    }
  }
  console.log("Total number of valid check numbers is " + correctChecks);
  console.log("Total number of invalid check numbers is " + invalidChecks);
  console.log("Total number of invalid amounts is " + invalidAmounts);
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly impressive, I have not seen this type of use of indexof (especially how you  are utilizing it with the for loop and both values of the array's). This worked flawlessly with what I needed it for and you have given me a new way to think about using the indexOf(). Thanks!